# using curves for animation

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I was just wondering why I don't see people using curves for bone animation? although I'm sure it has its downs I don't see anything wrong with that besides its a little slower. and since I'm a visual person, it would be easier to see what the bone does. is there a reason people don't do this?

Comment: Hello, could you please show some examples?

Comment: hey. not as of now since im on my school laptop and that wouldent be able to do something like that very well. i will give an example when i get home